Putting a function into a module changes its result
As described here after some problems I found a way to save functions generated with SymEnginge and load them in a new session. However for some reason this stops working, when I put the function that generates the expressions into a module.
So what I can do is first use
using Serialization
using SymEngine

function lambdify_an(ex, vars = [])
    body = convert(Expr, ex)
    if isempty(vars)
        syms = Symbol.(free_symbols(ex))
    else
        syms = Symbol.(vars)
    end
    fn = eval(:($(Expr(:tuple,syms...)) -> $body));
    return(fn)
end


function pow(n)
    @vars X
    expr = X^n
    return(lambdify_an(expr, [X]))
end

fs = [pow(2), pow(3)]
println(fs[1](2))
serialize("pow.ser", fs)

, to generate a file named pow.ser, that contains my list of 2 functions. I can then in a new Session call:
using Serialization
using SymEngine


fs = deserialize("pow.ser")
println(fs[1](2))

to load the functions again and everything works fine.
Now, if I instead define a module in a file called mwe_module.jl
module minex
using SymEngine
export pow
function lambdify_an(ex, vars = [])
    body = convert(Expr, ex)
    if isempty(vars)
        syms = Symbol.(free_symbols(ex))
    else
        syms = Symbol.(vars)
    end
    fn = eval(:($(Expr(:tuple,syms...)) -> $body));
    return(fn)
end

function pow(n)
    @vars X
    expr = X^n
    return(lambdify_an(expr, [X]))
end
end

and then use the function in the module to generate my function list
include("mwe_module.jl")
using .minex
using Serialization
fs = [pow(2), pow(3)]
println(fs[1](2))
serialize("pow.ser", fs);

and then try to load it in a new Session
include("mwe_module.jl")
using .minex
using Serialization
using SymEngine

fs = deserialize("pow.ser")
println(fs[1](2))

, I get an error, namely:
ERROR: UndefVarError: #1#2 not defined
Stacktrace:
  [1] deserialize_datatype(s::Serializer{IOStream}, full::Bool)
    @ Serialization C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.8.5\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:1364
  [2] handle_deserialize(s::Serializer{IOStream}, b::Int32)
    @ Serialization C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.8.5\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:866 
  [3] deserialize(s::Serializer{IOStream})
    @ Serialization C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.8.5\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:813 
  [4] handle_deserialize(s::Serializer{IOStream}, b::Int32)
    @ Serialization C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.8.5\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:873 
  [5] deserialize_fillarray!(A::Vector{Function}, s::Serializer{IOStream})
    @ Serialization C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.8.5\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:1256
  [6] deserialize_array(s::Serializer{IOStream})
    @ Serialization C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.8.5\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:1248
  [7] handle_deserialize(s::Serializer{IOStream}, b::Int32)
    @ Serialization C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.8.5\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:864 
  [8] deserialize(s::Serializer{IOStream})
    @ Serialization C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.8.5\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:813 
  [9] handle_deserialize(s::Serializer{IOStream}, b::Int32)
    @ Serialization C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.8.5\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:919 
 [10] deserialize
    @ C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.8.5\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:813 [inlined]     
 [11] deserialize(s::IOStream)
    @ Serialization C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.8.5\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:800 
 [12] open(f::typeof(deserialize), args::String; kwargs::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
    @ Base .\io.jl:384
 [13] open
    @ .\io.jl:381 [inlined]
 [14] deserialize(filename::String)
    @ Serialization C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.8.5\share\julia\stdlib\v1.8\Serialization\src\Serialization.jl:810
 [15] top-level scope
    @ c:\Users\username\projektpath\min_mwe\min_mwe_load_module.jl:6

I do not understand, what is happening and I also find this consequence of putting something into a module rather unexpected. So what is happening? Is this intended behavior? Is there a better way of putting the function into a module?

eval evaluates an expression in a module. It seems the definition of the deserialized function is done inside a module and is not visible to the Main module. The redefinition needs to be using eval from the Module you wish to use the function at (each module has a different eval method defined in it). (See also @eval 2 parameter version)
